# Add downloaded resources (images) to Bundle?

Tags: ios, resources, uiimage, bundle, resourcebundle

I am developing an application which is a kind of contact list. This list is updated each times the applications starts.
Each contact in the list has its own photo. A part of this list is common for every user of this application. For this part, I already have all the needed pics and I inlude them in the bundle/archive (which will be sent to Apple).
The pics of the new contacts (added during the lifetime of the app) are downloaded from a remote server (using ASIHTTPRequest). But I don't know how to handle these downloaded pics easily.

I am looking for a way to add these downloaded pics to the main bundle so I can call them using :

```
+ (UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name
```

Do you have any idea of the good practices for this kind of things ?
If new resources can't be added to the main bundle, what are your recommendations ?

Thanks again for your help !

kheraud

Comment: kheraud, I have a similar situation as I'm download some images and I would like to use imageNamed so it can benefit of cache. Did you figure out a solution for it?

Comment: No, I made my static loadImageFromBundleOrFolder using imageWithContentsOfFile. But I don't use caching for the image retrieved in folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only add files to your App's Documents directory. The main bundle can't be modified after your App has been released. Read the documentation on how to write to the directory.

Edit_: This should help you to get started http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW6

Comment: Thanks for the URL. Do you have standard / common ways to retieve downloaded files using "+ (UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name" ? I guess a common mechanic is built-in with no need to create it's own one looking in directories... UIImages functions includes caching systems, I would benefit of it also.

Comment: I don't know if I got you right. But to retrieve the images with imageNamed, you have to attach the path to your documents directory to the filename of your image. It's pretty simple by using a formatted NSString ([[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", docDirectoryPath, imageFilename]) and the just use that string in your imageNamed: method call. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: In fact, imageNamed function permits to have a caching system for image loaded. But, "the method looks for an image with the specified name in the application’s main bundle". So I am wondering if there is a way to benefit of this caching system with downloaded images. It seems you can't add images to the main bundle... So, you can't use imageNamed method... So you cant' benefit of the caching system brought with this method ? any alternative ?

Comment: Ah, sorry had the wrong method in mind. Use " [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath]" instead of imageNamed. This will allow you to open images from the docs dir.

Comment: "This method does not cache the image object.". I am looking for a way to benefit of the caching system. It seems impossible.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really get what you're trying to achieve. If you're already downloading the images to the apps documents directory, what else do you want to cache and why?

Comment: You want to cache the image in memory because disk access is expensive.  Because the method `imageWithContentsOfFile:` does not cache, you can achieve your own caching by storing the image as a property and writing your own getter method.  Store the image in a private member var. The getter method checks that value. If the value is not nil, simply return the image. If it is nil, then call `imageWithContentsOfFile:` to give it a value before returning it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing a similar thing for an app, and in the past I've used a couple of different Categories for UIImage.

For the current version I'm looking at https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage but I had really good luck using this one in a previous version https://github.com/jaanus/UIImageViewCached. For my purpose, I was downloading images from a URL and then caching them for use in a TableView.

HTH

Comment: 8month later, I reach the same conclusion : SDWebImage is the easiest solution.